# How to detect if mod_rewrite is available?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Good day. I have a problem with links in my application. I want to use '`pretty-urls'`,so i want to all my links look like '`www.sitename.com/controller/method`'. So i want to print my all my links through one function,which would look like

```
function link($url_segments) {
  if(mod_rewrite_is_available) 
     return BASE_URL.$url_segments;
  else
     return BASE_URL."index.php".$url_segments;
}
```

But i can't understand how to detect if server has rewrite module enabled. I have found 2 solutions:

1. Place in config some variable(like codeigniter does) like
   `$config["index_variable"]` to use inside my function,but that means
   that all my clients will need to change that line in config when
   installing application on hosting
2. Use function to detect mod_rewrite,like apache_get_modules,but like
   i understood it can be not avaibale on some hosting,and what if
   server will be nginx?

So i want to know,how to detect that and print my links.

Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just provide the .htaccess to your clients so that, when you upload the files, it turns the rewrite mod on?

Comment: This is frequently done. I suppose it's expected that those using non-Apache servers will have to adapt the rules to their server of choice.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very tricky and hard, personally, I would go with the fallback approach.

1. Look at `apache2handler`'s loaded modules (via [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo)) to see if `mod_rewrite` is there
2. Try `sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` to see if mod_rewrite is loaded
3. Try to use a `.htaccess` file to see if everything is working.
4. Try to determine the server software used, and parse the conf file for the server
5. Use worst case of no `mod_rewrite` is enabled, and then enable it manually after  the software has been installed.

Comment: Wow,so fast answers. Thanks,i decided that it is too complicated. Pretty urls in general are used for search engine optimization,so i think in backend i will use links like index.php?url=controller/method,and in settings will be option 'Use pretty urls for frontend if you are sure that rewrite_module is enabled'. Something like that. )