# read mod_rewrite config from within PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a piece of PHP software that does beautifull things with mod_rewrite.  But the same software should run on a server where mod_rewrite isn't installed.   Can I check in my php code if mod_rewrite is installed AND if a certain rule is applied?

For example, something like this:

```
    if ((mod_rewrite is enabled) and (mod_rewrite_rule is OK)){
        return  createBeautifullLink();
    }else{
        return createUglyLink();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301118/how-to-detect-mod-rewrite-without-apache-get-modules or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284621/how-to-detect-if-mod-rewrite-is-available

Comment: Check this out : http://christian.roy.name/blog/detecting-modrewrite-using-php

Comment: I think the only really reliable method is actually accessing the URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this:

in **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # inform php that mod_rewrite is enabled
   SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE on
   ...
```

in **PHP**:

```
$mod_rewrite = FALSE;
if (function_exists("apache_get_modules")) {
   $modules = apache_get_modules();
   $mod_rewrite = in_array("mod_rewrite",$modules);
}
if (!isset($mod_rewrite) && isset($_SERVER["HTTP_MOD_REWRITE"])) {
   $mod_rewrite = ($_SERVER["HTTP_MOD_REWRITE"]=="on" ? TRUE : FALSE); 
}
if (!isset($mod_rewrite)) {
   // last solution; call a specific page as "mod-rewrite" have been enabled; based on result, we decide.
   $result = file_get_contents("http://somepage.com/test_mod_rewrite");
   $mod_rewrite  = ($result=="ok" ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

The first (apache) can be disabled by server, the second **custom one** will exist in **$_SERVER** only if [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html) is installed.
So what i think as best solution is to create a **fake** url redirection in your .htaccess that points to some file of yours (that return simply an "ok") and call that with the redirection from a .php; if returns "ok", you can use clean urls...
The redirection code in *.htaccess* might looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   ...
   RewriteEngine on
   # fake rule to verify if mod rewriting works (if there are unbearable restrictions..)
   RewriteRule ^test_mod_rewrite/?$    index.php?type=test_mod_rewrite [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey,  thanks for this.  i also thought of this, but adding a page request on every page request is bit of a performance killer.  So I'm creating some sort of 'check installation page'.  This page is writing <?php $rewriteOk = true/false ?> to a file. This file then get's included for every request.   That solved the performance hit for me.  As I believe that this server configurations (almost) never change this is good for me.

Comment: yes, of course this would kill the performance and is not normal; just call it once in 'installation' fashion and store a value in your database; in case something will prove wrong (while your server support clean urls, suddenly not) you can call that again

Answer (score 3):

(The following works if PHP is **not** in CGI)

Try this :

```
if (function_exists('apache_get_modules')) {
   $modules = apache_get_modules();
   $mod_rewrite = in_array('mod_rewrite', $modules);
} else {
   $mod_rewrite =  getenv('HTTP_MOD_REWRITE')=='On' ? true : false ;
}
```

or this : [How to detect mod_rewrite without apache_get_modules()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301118/how-to-detect-mod-rewrite-without-apache-get-modules)

Credits goes to [Christian Roy](http://christian.roy.name/blog/detecting-modrewrite-using-php)

Comment: Plus it checks for the module only, it says nothing about whether the rewrite rule is okay.

Comment: @rkosegi : I usually give credit where due, check my previous answers, if you care about copy-pasting checking.

Comment: Well, kind of. AFAIK, this will only work if PHP is running as an Apache module. In CGI mode, PHP will have no access to the server's installed modules.